# Why this is printing "operator + operator +" as out put? Could somebody please shed some light on this?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Why this is printing "operator + operator +" as out put? my expectation was "operator + double operator +". Could somebody  please shed some light on this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


     struct mydata{
        int mx;
        mydata(int x = 0){}
        mydata operator+(const mydata& rhs){
                cout<<" operator + ";
                mydata temp(rhs);
                return temp;
        }
        operator int() const{cout<<" int "; return mx; }
        operator double() const{cout<" double "; return mx; }
};


int main(){
        mydata d;
        mydata r = d + mydata(5); // L1
        5 + (double)d; // L2
        d + d; // L3
}
```

Comment: try this: `5 + double(d); // L2`

Comment: Works for me. You've got a missing `<` in `cout<" double "`; I wouldn't expect that to compile (but if it does, that's your problem).

Comment: [it works](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4G49OA$0)

Comment: after adding the extra `<` it compiles and outputs `operator +  double  operator +` with g++

Answer (score 1):

`cout<" double "` should be `cout << " double "`.
I'm surprised that compiles as is.

Comment: omg !  cout<" double " compiling for me even without a warning!  why is it so? lol

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, this compiles and runs with `VS2008` and produces OP's answer and this easy to miss warning:

```
warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
```

However GCC does go out with a bang when compiling (which is actually nice):

```
test.cpp: In member function 'mydata::operator double() const':
test.cpp:14: error: no match for 'operator<' in 'std::cout < " double "'
test.cpp:14: note: candidates are: operator<(const char*, const char*) <built-in>
test.cpp:14: note:                 operator<(void*, void*) <built-in>
```

So if OP is using `VS` it might be good to keep an eye on the warnings.